# Django Advanced Annotate

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Given this model:

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    needs_attention = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

I can `annotate` the list of posts with:

```
Post.objects.annotate(last_comment_date=Max('comment__created_at'))
```

to know the `last_comment_date`, how to annotate to set a value for `last_comment_needs_attention`?

Comment: kindly explain your question a little more."to set a value for last_comment_needs_attention"

Comment: Yes please, I would like to now if the last comment of a `Post` has the flag `needs_attention` set to `True`. Does it explain?

Comment: you can use filter Post.objects.filter(need_attention=True).annotate(last_comment_date=Max('comment__created_at'))

Comment: Sorry, I need all the Posts and I want to have a value which is ´last_comment_needs_attention´.

what you say can be done with `Post.objects.filter(comment__needs_attention=True)` but it means get all the post that have a comment with `needs_attention` set to True. That is completely different.

Comment: You might be able to do that using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

Comment: Any examples, Please?

Comment: I have searched and I have found no way to obtain that value with conditional expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
needs_attention = Q(comment__needs_attention=True)
Post.objects.annotate(last_comment_date=Max('comment__created_at'), filter=needs_attention)
```